# Monitoring of Azure Web App Linux based Container

Tags: containers, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I would like to know the best way to monitor Linux containers in Azure Web App. Main parameters I wanted to monitor was the containers memory usage, CPU, health of the containers etc.
I tried with Azure Monitor's Container section, I don't see any containers being listed from my Azure App Service. I think Azure Monitor is mainly for containers from AKS, Container Instance.

Answer (score 0):

In Diagnose and Solve problems blade in Azure portal we can see memory usage, CPU etc.. Container wise we don't have a monitoring because there are multiple containers running for a single webapp like the main app container, kudu container, middleware container if enabled, msi container if enabled..
Please let me know if you have further queries.

Answer (score 0):

For Web Apps you can also consider Application Insights  Or you might also consider, if you haven't already, Azure Container Apps. Its essentially a "minified" instance of AKS and there are specific options described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/metrics